# Реализация кода на C++ работает медленнее, чем на Python

Tags: python, c++, файлы, производительность

Написал две одинаковые программы на Python и C++ и заметил, что Python быстрее, но почему? Обе программы деают следующее: вы вводите строку, из символов которой буду создаваться все возможные вариации, длины которых варьируются от 4 до n символов, где n - длина введенной строки. Создается директория, с указанным пользователем названием, в которой создаются несколько файлов с названиями comb_i.txt, где i - длина вариаций, который записаны в файле.

Код на Python:

```
import os
import itertools

s = input('Введите пароль: ')
chars = set(s)
n = input('Введите имя: ')
os.mkdir(f'Passes_{n}')

for i in range(4, len(s) + 1):
    with open(f'Passes_{n}/comb_{i}.txt', 'w') as file:
        for combo in itertools.permutations(chars, i):
            file.write("".join(combo) + "\n")
print('Все пароли сгенерированы')
```

Код на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <sys/stat.h> // Для создания директории
#include <filesystem> // Для работы с файловой системой
#include <sstream> // Для преобразования числа в строку

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void generate_permutations(string& current_input, unordered_set<string>& variations, int start_index, int length) {
    if (start_index == length) {
        variations.insert(current_input.substr(0, length));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start_index; i < current_input.length(); ++i) {
        swap(current_input[start_index], current_input[i]);
        generate_permutations(current_input, variations, start_index + 1, length);
        swap(current_input[start_index], current_input[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    string user_input;
    cout << "Введите пароль: ";
    cin >> user_input;

    string folder_name;
    cout << "Введите название папки: ";
    cin >> folder_name;

    
    if (!fs::exists(folder_name)) {
        fs::create_directory(folder_name);
    }

    
    for (int i = 4; i <= user_input.length(); ++i) {
        unordered_set<string> variations;
        string current_input = user_input;
        sort(current_input.begin(), current_input.end());
        generate_permutations(current_input, variations, 0, i);

        
        string file_name = folder_name + "/comb_" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
        ofstream file(file_name, ios::out | ios::binary);
        if (file.is_open()) {
            stringstream ss;
            for (const auto& variation : variations) {
                ss << variation << '\n'; 
            }
            file << ss.str();
            file.close();
        }
    }

    cout << "Все пароли сгенерированы" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Замеры для C++:

```
$ time ./a.out  
Введите пароль: qwertyuiop
Введите название папки: Testcpp
Все пароли сгенерированы

real    18,06s
user    11,33s
sys 0,25s
cpu 64%
```

Замеры для Python:

```
$ time python3 passs.py  
Введите пароль: qwertyuiop
Введите имя: Testpy
Все пароли сгенерированы

real    11,21s
user    2,75s
sys 0,13s
cpu 25%
```

Comment: Модули для python обычно написаны на других яп поэтому если использовать модули и стандартные функции скорость может получиться больше.

Comment: Вы не сравниваете Python с C++, а сравниваете свою реализацию permutatuions с реализацией permutations из стандартной библиотеки Python, при этом [эта функция там реализована на Си](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fb8739f0b6291fb048a94d6312f59ba4d10a20ca/Modules/clinic/itertoolsmodule.c.h#L625). Т.е. не С++ медленнее чем Python, а ваша реализация медленнее. А вообще, желательно отделить файловые операции, чтобы понять что именно тормозит.

Comment: Как-то читал графа Игнатьева :), момент — он в Париже на мели. Пока не прислали деньги, ходил по дешевым бистро. Зашел, скромно заказал что-то типа бутерброда с пивом. Тут рядом садится девица, заказывает то, се, еще и это и вон то... У графа слюнки текут, а счета им притащили практически одинаковые. "В каждой стране надо уметь жить" — такой вывод делает граф. Перефразируя его, "каждым языком надо уметь пользоваться"...

Comment: @insolor в таком случае, как можно было бы улучшить реализацию?

Comment: В первую очередь я бы проверил что именно тормозит - нахождение перестановок или файловые операции. Если перестановки, то попробовать например заменить рекурсивный алгоритм на итеративный. P.S. а вообще да, в первую очередь стоило бы проверить, нет ли вдруг стандартной реализации.

Comment: std::next_permutation

Comment: ¿А где тут замеры времени? ¿Зачем в коде на С++ создаются промежуточные контейнеры и stringstream?

Comment: Во входной строке все символы должны быть уникальны? Или допускается такое: `aabccd`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy допускается, но в конечном результате создаются только пароли, в которых символы уникальны. Да, это вызывает противоречие, если будет введена строка с повторяющимися символами, тк в таком случае невозможно будет создать строку длиной n - k, где n - это длина введенной строки, а k - количество уникальных символов в строке, но это было сделано, чтобы избежать паролей с повторяющимися символами. Данная проблема возникает из за того, что из строки создается множество chars(это видно в коде на python)

Comment: Укажите флаги, с которыми компилировали плюсовую программу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я воспроизвёл с `-O3`. Она всё равно отстаёт из-за ненужной хеш-таблицы.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, программы на Питоне и на C++ дают разные результаты если на вход дана строка с не уникальными символами. В такой ситуации их просто нельзя сравнивать. Везде дальше я буду работать только с уникальными символами.

Во-вторых, чтобы было удобно сравнивать я избавлюсь от файлового вывода. Вот так:

```py
import itertools


s = input()
for i in range(4, len(s) + 1):
    for p in itertools.permutations(s, i):
        print(''.join(p))
```

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

void generate_permutations(string& current_input, unordered_set<string>& variations, int start_index, int length) {
    if (start_index == length) {
        variations.insert(current_input.substr(0, length));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start_index; i < static_cast<int>(current_input.length()); ++i) {
        swap(current_input[start_index], current_input[i]);
        generate_permutations(current_input, variations, start_index + 1, length);
        swap(current_input[start_index], current_input[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    
    for (int i = 4; i <= static_cast<int>(s.length()); ++i) {
        unordered_set<string> variations;
        string current_input = s;
        sort(current_input.begin(), current_input.end());
        generate_permutations(current_input, variations, 0, i);
        
        for (const auto& variation : variations) {
            cout << variation << '\n'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Сравнение за одну минуту показывает что результаты одинаковые:

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -O3 permutations.cpp 
>
> $ time diff <(echo 0123456789 | python permutations.py | sort) <(echo 0123456789 | ./a.out | sort)
>
> real  0m38.229s
> user  0m54.528s
> sys   0m1.072s
> ```

Теперь сравниваем время работы. Шесть секунд Питон, восемь - С++:

> ```
> $ time echo 0123456789 | python permutations.py | wc -l
> 9863280
>
> real  0m5.695s
> user  0m5.788s
> sys   0m0.080s
>
> $ time echo 0123456789 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 9863280
>
> real  0m8.144s
> user  0m7.916s
> sys   0m0.168s
> ```

Причина медлительности C++ в накоплении результатов в `unordered_set`. Зачем это делать? Если все символы уникальны, то и все результаты будут уникальны.

Убираем хеш-таблицу:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void generate_permutations(string& current_input, int start_index, int length) {
    if (start_index == length) {
        cout << current_input.substr(0, length) << '\n';
        return;
    }
    for (int i = start_index; i < static_cast<int>(current_input.length()); ++i) {
        swap(current_input[start_index], current_input[i]);
        generate_permutations(current_input, start_index + 1, length);
        swap(current_input[start_index], current_input[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    
    for (int i = 4; i <= static_cast<int>(s.length()); ++i) {
        generate_permutations(s, 0, i);
    }
}
```

Я проверил через `diff` что результат не изменился. Время C++ теперь в семь раз лучше чем у Питона. Не плохо для столь простой реализации:

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -O3 permutations-2.cpp 
>
> $ time echo 0123456789 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 9863280
>
> real  0m0.761s
> user  0m0.844s
> sys   0m0.056s
> ```

Comment: `Время C++ теперь в семь раз лучше чем у Питона.` Весь код не смотрел, но чего это такой разрыв образовался? Ведь `сравниваете свою реализацию permutatuions с реализацией permutations из стандартной библиотеки Python, при этом эта функция там реализована на Си.`

Comment: @wololo, да, `itertools.permutations` написана на Си. Но каждая итерация цикла вызывает код на Питоне, чтобы собрать строку из перестановки и напечатать её.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy даже при вводе строки с уникальными символами программа выводила рез-ты типа qqqq, qqqe и тд. Именно поэтому был прикручен `unordered_set`. Теперь вижу, что создание множества из элементов строки было глупой идеей, тк не разобрался в работе `permutations`. Спасибо